# C: Hook into tshark to get access to analyzed layers of packets

Tags: c, tshark, pyshark

I want to get access to analyzed packet layer information (that tshark does very well) in a C program.

Is there a library interface for tshark that can be used to gather analysis information from packets of a pcap file?

PS: Higher layer languages is not an option for me. I have it working with pyshark (Python) but is too slow for my need(pyshark invokes tshark command line and processes the response json). I need a way to directly get tshark output to my C program.

Answer (score 2):

You probably will want [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) for this, if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: AFAIK, libpcap does not analyze the packet for you, tshark/wireshark does analysis.

Comment: Here is a list you might find useful : https://github.com/caesar0301/awesome-pcaptools#analysis

Comment: For me a question: Can libpcap analyze all packet as wireshark or tshark?